# Django ORM. How does Django know the auto incremented pk of newly created record

Tags: mysql, django

Suppose `Book` table has two fields `id`, `name`. `id` is auto incremented pk.
Database back end is mysql

In Django.

`book = Book.objects.create(name="Tender Is the Night")`

How does Django know new book's id.

What sql statements dose Django send to Mysql server?

Only the insert statement ? if so，does insert statement will return the id of newly created book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a MySQL feature. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
    ('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
    ('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals;
```

> No value was specified for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically.

Django uses the relevant database API (MySQL, in this case) to find out the last inserted ID:

> You can retrieve the most recent automatically generated `AUTO_INCREMENT` value with the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` SQL function or the `mysql_insert_id()` C API function. These functions are connection-specific, so their return values are not affected by another connection which is also performing inserts.

See the relevant source code for details: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L874

```
def _do_insert(self, manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw):
        """
        Do an INSERT. If update_pk is defined then this method should return
        the new pk for the model.
        """
        return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
                               using=using, raw=raw)
```